# Web service for converting Microsoft Office file formats (doc, docx, ppt, etc) into plain text?

Tags: webapp-rec, webservice, microsoft-office

Larger context: we're working on an Intranet portal's search engine, which needs to be able to search within ALL office types: `.doc`, `.docx`, `.xls`, `.xlsx`, `.ppt`, and `.pptx`. Having the search also already in place, we've implemented the indexer using Office automation; however, client is concerned, that this is 1, error-prone, and 2, not recommended by Microsoft (and also -not covered in their license).

I've read the previous answers in this regard on SO, however it would require us to integrate an extremely large amount of distinct libraries to cover all the edges, which we don't have the resource to do.

Hence, we're looking for a simple web service, to which we can submit any of these documents, and would return a simple, plain text (or HTML, or even PDF -we've got parsers for both) output.

Are there any such services (free, or paid) that cover all of the file formats above?

Answer (score 1):

[Online PDF Converter](http://www.freepdfconvert.com/) seems to be what you are looking for. You can either convert for free (and send the converted document to an email) or buy a [membership](http://www.freepdfconvert.com/membership.asp).

Answer (score 1):

[Saaspose](http://saaspose.com) is the solution of your problem, using this free App not only you can convert your document to a variety of other formats but also create your document whether its Word document or PDF from scratch online.